Is there a standalone rule for when concealment can't be used to Hide?
Some (but not all) features that provide concealment say you can't use their concealment to Hide. Many of them imply that this is the "usual" rule, despite seeming not to be universal.
Fey sorcerer's Blood Magic (PC2, p. 152) is declared to be an "obvious" effect that can't be used to Hide. It doesn't mention Sneak:

Colorful fey ribbons dance around you. Either you gain a +2 status bonus to Performance checks for 1 round, or you can become concealed for 1 round. Such obvious concealment can't be used to Hide.

Mistform Elixir calls out your position as being obvious, rather than the effect. It implies this is the "usual" rule and also prevents both Hide and Sneak:

A faint mist emanates from your skin, making you concealed for the listed duration. As usual, if you become concealed when your position is still obvious, you can't use this concealment to Hide or Sneak.

Fade into Daydreams from the Wandering Reverie subconscious mind is similar (though it omits Sneak):

Your flights of imagination spill into the real world, causing you to become indistinct, hazy, or cloaked in figments. You become concealed until the start of your next turn. This concealment can't be used to Hide, as normal for concealing effects that leave your location obvious.

Kineticist's Clear as Air impulse makes you concealed (instead of the usual invisibility) if you use it again within 10 minutes. It doesn't provide any restrictions on Hide/Sneak:

This impulse weakens if you use it too frequently. Using it again within 10 minutes makes you concealed instead of invisible.

Wall of fire makes everything on one side of the wall concealed to creatures on the other (in both directions). It also doesn't limit Hide/Sneak:

Everything on each side of the wall is concealed from creatures on the opposite side.

I checked the rules for Perception and Detection, the concealed condition, the Hide action, and more, but was unable to find a standalone rule that (some of) these features seem to refer to. Does one exist?

In Pathfinder Second Edition, specific rules trump more general rules.
Found under Game Conventions on pg.399 of the Player core:

Specific Overrides General
A core principle of Pathfinder is that specific rules override general ones. If two rules conflict, the more specific one takes precedence. If there's still ambiguity, the GM determines which rule to use. For example, the rules state that when attacking a concealed creature, you must attempt a DC 5 flat check to determine if you hit. Flat checks don't benefit from modifiers, bonuses, or penalties, but an ability that's specifically designed to overcome concealment might override and alter this. While some special rules may also state the normal rules to provide context, you should always default to the general rules presented in this chapter, even if effects don't specifically say to.
(Playing the Game, and
Perception and Detection, Nethys. Emphasis mine, and I included the whole block because it contains rules relevant to Concealment.)

Because general rules for Perception, Hiding, and Concealment exist, it is a part of the design philosophy of P2e to have the specific abilities, spells, and feats that override these general rules to include such within their descriptions. These are the general rules you are looking for.
To your examples, an explanation
Your examples include:

As usual, if you become concealed when your position is still obvious, you can't use this concealment to Hide or Sneak. (Links are Nethys)

This is because in order to Hide you must either have some sort of Cover or have Concealment in a way that you are no longer Observed.
Concealment, by itself, is not sufficient to Hide. You must also not be Observed by the creature you are attempting to Hide from. In all of your examples, the character is still Observed.
The general rules for Stealth may be found on pages 244-245 of the Player Core.
Or at Archives of Nethys here.

Being Stealthy
If you want to sneak around when there are creatures that can see you, you can use a combination of Hide and Sneak to do so.
First, Hide behind something (either by taking advantage of cover or having the concealed condition due to fog, a spell, or a similar effect). A successful Stealth check makes you hidden, though the creatures still know roughly where you are... (Nethys, Sneak, emphasis mine).

It can also be inferred from the Hide action on page 244 (though admittedly this is not a directly stated rule, per se):

You huddle behind cover or greater cover or deeper into concealment to become hidden, rather than observed. (Nethys, Hide, emphasis mine)

Further emphasized by

If you successfully become hidden to a creature but then cease to...be concealed from it, you become observed again. (Hide, emphasis mine)


The main purpose of the Hide action is to go from Observed to Hidden, so I'm not sure how "not being Observed" would be a prerequisite for attempting to Hide. Are you saying that you can never Hide using any form of concealment (without cover)?

@Yeah whoops I worded that a little weird, but essentially if its an ability that still makes your position obvious, you can't use it to become hidden. I'll edit later
